# How to implement Lazy Loading

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView` that loads 10 items at a time. When I reach the end of my list I add 10 elements at a time as I am trying to achieve lazy loading ListView, but my issue is when I have 26 elements in my list, it loads the first 20 but after that displays the last 6 and shows a range error for the remaining 4. Can somebody help me solve this problem? This is my attempt so far -

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          if (notification.metrics.extentBefore ==
              notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
             if(listView.length%10 == listView.length%counter) {
                counter+=10;
          } else {
                count.value = gameList.value.length%10;
//error comes when the total value of list is NOT a multiple of 10 (causes range error)
              }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

- replace 'listView.length+=10;' with 'listView.add(NewItemList[i]);'

as this code :

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
  onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
      if (notification.metrics.extentBefore ==
          notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
          for(int i=0;i<NewItemList.length;i++)
           setState(
            {listView.add(NewItemList[i]);}); //here replace
         //error comes when the total value of list is NOT a multiple of 10 (causes range error)
      }
    }
```

Comment: I specifically want to add 10 items at a time

Comment: Select the number of new 10 items
Before adding them to  List

ListView is List from your model 
List<YourModel> listview;
Then setState();

Comment: Can you update your example @Hossambo Bin Aref

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

`````
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          if (notification.metrics.extentBefore ==
              notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
             if((listView.length - counter) >= 10 ) {
                counter+=10;
          } else {
                counter += listView.length - counter;
         }
          }
        }````
`````